# Get AudioPlayer state on Titanium Mobile for Android

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm having a bit of trouble with a radio streaming app I'm working on for android. Everything in the app is working great apart from this one tiny bit, so it's very frustrating.

I would like to be able to capture the current playback state of the AudioPlayer, so that my application can take action when buffering/network changes occur.

For example, today my connection changed from 3G to Wi-Fi, which caused the player to stop dead, and freeze.. Sometimes it stops for a second or two and then carries on OK.

I added some code into the event listener for change as below, to try and capture this:

```
player.addEventListener('change',function(e){

    if(e.state == player.STATE_WAITING_FOR_DATA){
            lblStatus.text = 'Reconnecting in 10s';
        setTimeout(reconnect,10000); // This fires a reconnect function further down in my code.
    }

});
```

However, the change event is simply not fired. It's almost like the process of waiting for the data stream is causing the change event not to fire.

So I thought another way to do this would be to set an interval to call a stream check function every 1 second, like this.

```
setInterval(checkStream,1000);

function checkStream(){
    if(player.state == player.STATE_WAITING_FOR_DATA){
        // Add reconnect code here
    }
}
```

This didn't work either. When I added a debug alert to show the value of `player.state` it was null all the time, even when playing. In the Titanium Studio IDE it says this property isn't available on android. However in the API docs on the website it says they are. I believe the IDE.

As a last resort, I decided to capture the change event of the Ti.Network, and run the reconnect code once the connection is detected as being back online. However, sometimes this is not needed, and disconnects & reconnects the stream when it actually doesn't need to do so.

Is there any other way to capture the state of the AudioPlayer, or would just sticking with the Network change event be the only way to go about this?

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this?

Comment: No, Peter. I never did come across a resolution for this. In the end I just decided to bite the bullet and not bother monitoring it. I may delve back in to this though and see if there is something that can be done.

Comment: I just posted an answer that may or may not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since I used the AudioPlayer functionality to roll my own playlist, it was very important to detect when a track was finished so I could request the next one.  The events are raised for both Android and iOS, [but the actual STATE is not available on Android (3.0 SDK)](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Media.AudioPlayer-property-state).  Not a very useful event on Android.  Here's what I went with:

```
var nextTrackIfEnd = function() { 

    if (Ti.Platform.name === 'android')
    {
        $.debug.text = "isPlaying: " + audioPlayer.isPlaying();
        if(!audioPlayer.isPlaying() && hasStarted)
        {
            nextTrack();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $.debug.text = "state: " + audioPlayer.state;
        if(audioPlayer.state == 0)
        {
            nextTrack();
        }
    }
};
setInterval(nextTrackIfEnd, 500);
```